# Alternatives to SVD for rank factorization

Tags: algorithms, machine-learning, numerical-analysis, linear-algebra

I have rank-deficient matrix $M \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ with $\text{rank}(M) = k$ and I want to find a [rank factorization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_factorization) $M = PQ$ with $P \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times k}$ and $Q \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times m}$.

A popular approach is to compute the singular value decomposition (SVD) $M = UDV^*$ and keep the columns of $U$ and rows of $V$ corresponding to the non-zero singular values. This is a great approach, especially since it behaves nicely under noise. However, SVD seems to compute more than I need for just rank factorization (and the noise tolerance is cool, but not necessary).

**What are the other approaches I can use?** In particular, I am interested in algorithms that have *one* (or more) of the following properties:

1. Outperform SVD asymptotically.
2. Outperform SVD in practice, or on special inputs (for a reasonably interesting class of special inputs).
3. Performance under small perturbation of $M$ is well understood.

I am fine with giving $k$ to the algorithm ahead of time. Note that SVD does not require this (unless we are doing a perturbation analysis, but even then we usually give a bound on perturbation size and determine $k$ at run-time based on that).

Comment: Minpack uses a qr decomposition with pivoting. Even a normal LU decomposition (=Gaussian elimination) with pivoting is able to do the trick. There are also Krylov subspace based methods to compute the SVD. For a general matrix, all these methods are O(n^2 m), assuming no tricks like Strassen multiplication are used. I decided against giving more details here, because [Computational Science](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com) would be a much better place to ask such questions, and I don't want to set wrong precedences.

Comment: Did you find an answer? If not you may want to repost this on [cstheory.se].

Comment: @Kaveh thanks, I will flag this question for migration to cstheory. Since you are a moderator there, I assume it is alright from that end?

Comment: @Artem, if it is possible it should be fine but unfortunately question older than 60 days cannot be migrated so you have to repost it manually.

Comment: @ArtemKaznatcheev What Kaveh said. Please remember to link from here to the new question.

Answer (score 3):

The proper search term in scientific journals is *"Rank-Revealing Decomposition"*. If You want some theoretic guarantees on numeric accuracy/stability, the search term would be *"Strong Rank-Revealing Decomposition"*. There seems to exist a (strong) rank-revealing version of almost every type of decomposition:

- Rank-Revealing QR Decomposition (RRQR)
  *(see Matrix Computations, 4th ed., Chapter 5.4.2 QR with Column Pivoting)*
- [Strong Rank-Revealing QR Decomposition](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Emgu/MA273/Strong_RRQR.pdf) (SRRQR)
- [Strong Rank-Revealing Cholesky Decomposition](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Eluiza/RRCh.pdf)
- [Strong Rank-Revealing LU Decomposition](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Eluiza/RRLU.pdf)

### Practically Outperforming SVD

Most SVD implementations, e.g. in LAPACK, are incredibly highly optimized. The opposite is true for strong rank-revealing decompositions: There seem to be no optimized implementations at all. A while ago, I came up with an [improved SRRQR variant](https://github.com/DirkToewe/srrqr_bin_py). One of my very rough [benchmarks](https://github.com/DirkToewe/nd4js/blob/master/benchmarks/bench_la_decomps.html) seem to indicate that the aforementioned SRRQR version *could* potentially outperform LAPACK's SVD after putting a lot of elbow grease into it. A lot of research and development would be required. The same is likely true for all the other strong rank-revealing decompositions.

The only rank-revealing decomposition used in practice seems to be the RRQR. It outperforms the SVD by a considerable margin but not by an order of magnitude. In fact, the RRQR is used as [part of the Jacobi SVD](https://netlib.org/lapack/lawnspdf/lawn169.pdf#page=16) in LAPACK.

### Theoretically Outperforming the SVD

It is my strong belief that we do not yet know enough about decomposition algorithms to answer this question. In 1969, Strassen already found an $\mathcal{O}(n^{\log_2{7}+\mathcal{o}(1)})$ [algorithm for matrix inversion](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02165411). Even faster algorithms like [Coppersmith-Winograd](https://www-auth.cs.wisc.edu/lists/theory-reading/2009-December/pdfmN6UVeUiJ3.pdf) have been found since. Do such algorithms exist for SVD? For (strong) rank-revealing decompositions? Can we make such algorithms numerically stable? As far as I know, we do not have the answers to these questions yet.

Most decompositions (including the SRRQR) use an $\mathcal{O}\left(\max{(m,n)}\cdot\min^2{(m,n)}\right)$ implementation, making their complexity identical in practice.

Current R&D seems to be heavily focused on sparse and tensor decompositions, so we will likely not get an answer to these questions any time soon.

### Numeric Accuracy/Stability

While RRQR works really accurately in practice, it is easy to construct synthetic examples where it fails completely (see Matrix Computations, 4th ed., Chapter 5.4.3).

The strong rank-revealing factorizations all make some theoretic guarantees of one kind of another which should make them more resilient to pathologically bad inputs.

Comment: I upvoted as this answered the question: RRQR is an alternative to SVD, is used in practice, and considerably outperforms SVD in practice.